# Chrome blocks my downloads

Tags: google-chrome, download

Chrome blocks my downloads if they contain something that resembles an executable, but works fine on other downloads:

[image]

This only happens in Chrome, all other browsers (Firefox, IE and Edge) are working correctly.

I have found the following advices through Google, but they didn't solve my case:

- [The chrome setting "Malware protection" is off](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/VTgECg1XT18/4f3MGlLXEgYJ), but the downloads are being blocked. [image]
- [The internet security settings "Download" setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/883260/information-about-the-attachment-manager-in-microsoft-windows) is not the issue: [image]
- [Chrome is obviously able to write into the download directory](https://www.rectanglered.com/tech-tip-google-chrome-download-error-insufficient-permissions), since documents are correctly downloaded.
- I have no Antivirus except Windows Defender.

How can I find out what causes the issue? Is there a log somewhere that could help me find the cause of the block?

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps you may disable "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites" temporarily. Keep in mind to re-enable it after you got your .exe.